# Loading and image with javascript. Where is my syntax wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am learning MVC using vanilla Javascript. I am trying to load an image when a button is pressed, but I believe my syntax is off.  Any ideas?

here are my scripts. I think the problem is in the View script, at the document.getElementById line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="Controller.js"></script>
    <script src="View.js"></script>
    <script src="Model.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body onload="buildImgArr()">

<div align="center">
<img id="imageFrame" >
</div>

<div  align="center">
<button id="loadImage" type="button" onclick="controlIMG()" >Click to load image</button>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

control script

```
function controlIMG(){

var randImg = randomImg();

loadIMG(randImg);
}
```

Model script

```
var myImages = new Array(2);

function buildImgArr(){
    //alert("In Array");
    myImages[1] = "hiragana/A.PNG";
    myImages[2] = "hiragana/CHI.PNG";
}

function randomImg(){
    //alert("in model");
    var rand = myImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length)];
    return rand;
}
```

View script

```
function loadIMG(imgsrc){
    alert("In view " + imgsrc);
    //text-align:center; margin: 0px auto; display:block
    document.getElementById("imageFrame").innerHTML = '<img src="imgsrc">';

}
```

Comment: What you think you get when you set `innerHTML = '<img src="imgsrc">';`? Is the variable name mysteriously extracted from the string to a live URL? + `img` can't have HTML, you need to put the image into another element, like div or sth. Or alternatively just set `src` of the existing image ...

Comment: check ur browser console

Comment: So one of your problems is that your variable wont resolve in a string so this '<img src="imgsrc">' should be '<img src="'+imgsrc+'">'. Also array indexes start at 0 so myImages[1] = "hiragana/A.PNG" should probably be 0 unless i'm missing something!

Comment: Thanks a ton @iSZ!

Comment: @Ryan Miles you're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the attribute of image using `setAttribute`. Here the use of `innerHTML` is wrong as it will try to add a html , but you just need to set the `src` of the `img`

```js
function controlIMG() {
  var randImg = randomImg();
  loadIMG(randImg);
}

var myImages = new Array(2);

function buildImgArr() {
  myImages[1] = "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/evening-in-the-forest-picture-id494297755?k=6&m=494297755&s=612x612&w=0&h=qn663JrZYf2hpu7SZc-SlrwrR5HjNr3yVcfyDqKHQmg=";
  myImages[2] = "https://d1ljaggyrdca1l.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Header-luxury-glass-suite-at-andbeyond-phinda-forest-lodge-on-a-luxury-safari-in-south-africa-1600x900.jpg";
}

function randomImg() {
  var rand = myImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * myImages.length)];
  return rand;
}


function loadIMG(imgsrc) {
  // using setAttribute method to dynamically set the src
  document.getElementById("imageFrame").setAttribute('src', imgsrc);

}
```

```css
.imageHolder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="buildImgArr()">

  <div align="center" class="imageHolder">
    <img id="imageFrame">
  </div>

  <div align="center">
    <button id="loadImage" type="button" onclick="controlIMG()">Click to load image</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: That also solved a problem I had where Firefox, but not Chrome would load my image. Thank you so much @brk!